# Whole Title Bar of the application layout is shown as link

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

we built an xpages app with the extlib application layout, and use the title bar for tabbed links. 
Irritating for the users is the effect that the whole title bar is shown as link, i.e. the mouse changes to a link symbol (hand) for the whole title bar row. 
Clickable are only the title bar tabs (as expected and correct), but users very often try to get "back home" by clicking on the title (left in the title bar). 
Did we create that effect by sth.? or is this the normal bootstrap (3.2.0) design?
thx, Uwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following CSS to your XPage(s):

```
.nav {
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Then, only tabbed links will have a pointer cursor in title bar.

This overwrites the settings in xsp-mixin.css:

```
/*Bootstrap relies on the href attribute on a's to show the correct cursor: fix for XPage pagination that by default doesn't have that*/
.nav, .pagination, .carousel a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I checked for side effects but couldn't find any issue with other elements not showing pointer cursor where needed.

Comment: Great - on first sight it looks perfect :-) 
I will do some testing tomorrow, and if I cannot find any side effect, implement it into our production environment.

Thanks a lot, Knut!